# Get most expensive and cheapest items from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the most expensive and cheapest items from two different tables.
The output should be one row with the values for MostExpensiveItem, MostExpensivePrice, CheapestItem, CheapestPrice

I was able to get the price of the most expensive and cheapest items in the two tables with following query:

```
SELECT
   MAX(ExtrasPrice) as MostExpensivePrice, MIN(ExtrasPrice) as CheapestPrice
FROM
    (
    SELECT ExtrasPrice FROM Extras
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ItemPrice FROM Items
    ) foo
```

How can I add the names of the items (ItemName, ExtrasName) to my output? Again, there should only be one row as the output.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FIRST_VALUE(Price) OVER (ORDER BY Price) AS MinPrice,
           FIRST_VALUE(Name) OVER (ORDER BY Price) AS MinName,
           LAST_VALUE(Price) OVER (ORDER BY Price DESC) AS MaxPrice,
           LAST_VALUE(Name) OVER (ORDER BY Price DESC) AS MaxName
    FROM (
        SELECT ExtrasName AS Name, ExtrasPrice AS Price FROM Extras
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ItemName As Name, ItemPrice AS Price FROM Items) u
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e37c/1)

Answer (score 1):

`TOP 1` with `order by` clause should work for you. Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 ExtrasPrice,ExtrasName
        FROM   Extras ORDER  BY ExtrasPrice Asc),
       (SELECT TOP 1 ItemPrice,ItemName
        FROM   Items ORDER  BY ItemPrice Desc)
```

**Note:** `Comma` can be replaced with `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: Just  a note, this will only return one max (or min) item, even if it's a tie.

Comment: @jarlh - I can add `TOP 1 with TIES` but OP wants *there should only be one row as the output*

Comment: CROSS JOIN didn't work for me. I had to add an AS statement after both ()

Comment: Besides that, it doesn't work as expected. If the cheapest item is in the Items table I still get the cheapest item from the Extras table as the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` for this.  If you are satisfied with two rows:

```
SELECT item, price
FROM (SELECT foo.*, row_number() over (order by price) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (order by price) as seqnum_desc
      FROM (SELECT item, ExtrasPrice as price FROM Extras
            UNION ALL
            SELECT item, ItemPrice FROM Items
           ) foo
     ) t
WHERE seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you have an index on "price" in both tables, then the cheapest method is probably:

```
with exp as (
     (select top 1 item, ExtrasPrice as price
       from Extras e
       order by price desc
     ) union all
     (select top 1 i.item, ItemPrice
      from Items i
      order by price desc
     )
    ),
    cheap as (
     (select top 1 item, ExtrasPrice as price
       from Extras e
       order by price asc
     ) union all
     (select top 1 i.item, ItemPrice
      from Items i
      order by price asc
     )
    )
select top 1 *
from exp
order by price desc
union all
select top 1 *
from cheap
order by price asc;
```

If you want this in one row, you can replace the final query with:

```
select e.*, c.*
from (select top 1 *
      from exp
      order by price desc
     ) e cross join
    (select top 1 *
     from cheap
     order by price asc
    ) c
```